# I get 'KeyError: Factory not registered: "user"' in the test of a controller with RSpec and Factory-bot-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, factory-bot

I'm working in a ToDo app, and I have an error when I run my tests for the controllers with FactoryBot.

The app is in Ruby on Rails, with Postgres as DB, RSpec and Shoulda-Matchers for testing, and FactoryBot-Rails.

The controller has a verifier that the user logs in previously, and it's necessary to load the user's lists. For this, I'm using FactoryBot to simulate an user.

When I run the test of my lists controller I get the error 'KeyError: Factory not registered: "user"'

I was reading a lot of blogs here in StackOverflow and other pages, and I tried all the solutions that I found, including:

- I made sure to use 'factory_bot_rails' in my Gemfile
- Try a file called 'factories' in my spec folder
- Try a file called user.rb in 'spec / factories / user.rb'
- Try with 'factory_girl_rails' (I know it's FactoryBot now, but I tried)
- Change the test with and without shoulda-matchers
- Change the type of the test
- Several or only 1 test at the same time
- Require 'factory_bot_rails' in my spec_helper.rb file
- Require my file or factories folder in my test file
- Include the "Syntax::Methods" in my rails_helper file

Defining 'user' factory in 'spec/factories.rb'

```
FactoryBot.define do 
  factory :user do
    first_name { "User1" }
    last_name { "UserLastName" }
    description { "A big guy" }
    email { "test@example.com" }
    password { "012345" }
  end
end
```

index to render in 'lists_controller.rb'

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
def index
  @lists = current_user.lists
end
```

Defining user for test, and test of render_template of index in 'lists_controllers_spec.rb'

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'factories/user'

RSpec.describe ListsController, type: :controller do

  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:list) { create(:list, user: user) }

  before do 
    sign_in user 
  end

  describe 'Get #index' do
    before { get :index }
    it { should render_template(:index) }
  end
end
```

In Gemfile I defined

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```

rails_helper.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production 
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if ails.env.production?

require 'rspec/rails'

begin
  ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!
rescue ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError => e
  puts e.to_s.strip
  exit 1
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  config.include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers, type: :controller 
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request 

  Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
    config.integrate do |with|
      with.test_framework :rspec
      with.library :rails
    end
  end
end
```

I expect that the test display that the render of index is working, but always I get

```
Failures:

  1) ListsController Get #index 
    Failure/Error: let(:user) { create(:user) }

    KeyError:
      Factory not registered: "user"
    # ./spec/controllers/lists_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    # ./spec/controllers/lists_controller_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
    # ------------------
    # --- Caused by: ---
    # KeyError:
    #   key not found: "user"
    #   ./spec/controllers/lists_controller_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00451 seconds (files took 1.04 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/lists_controller_spec.rb:30 # ListsController Get #index
```

spec_helper.rb

```
require 'factory_bot_rails'
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:all) do
    FactoryBot.reload
  end

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

  config.shared_context_metadata_behavior = :apply_to_host_groups
end
```

Comment: Wrap the code of the user factory within a `FactoryBot.define do; end` block.

Comment: I did not write it here, but it's exactly how I got it. I already added it in my description, sorry...

Comment: Do you define the user factory in `spec/factories.rb`? it should be a separate file, under the spec/factories/ folder for each factory, move the code for the user factory to a spec/factories/user.rb file.

Comment: I tried with both methods, in the same file in spec/fatorie.rb and in separate files in spec/factories/user.rb. Both of them give to me the same error.

Comment: How do your test look like? Are you including the `spec_helper` (`require 'spec_helper'`)?

Comment: In my test file I have ```require 'rails_helper'```, and there I have ```require 'spec_helper'```... and I also tried ```require 'spec_helper'``` in my test file and doesn't works. Btw, I have ```require 'factory_bot_rails'``` inside of my spec_helper.

Comment: Could you add the whole rails_helper and test file?

Comment: Done... I hope you can help me

Comment: Testing your configuration and it works. Do you have a spec_helper file?

Comment: I include the file spec_helper, if we omit the default comments from there, this is what I have in it.

Comment: Remove the `require 'factories/user'` in lists_controllers_spec.rb. Remove `require 'factory_bot_rails'` in spec_helper, and leave the factory always under the spec/factories folder.

Comment: I did it right now and it doesn't work. Btw, if I put a 'byebug' in ```'factories/user.br'``` file, the test never stops in the byebug unless I add ```require 'factories/user'``` at the top of the lists_controller_spec.rb file

Comment: Is it possible to share a repository?

Comment: You have mentioned that the `user` factory is defined in in `spec/factories.rb` . 
Try defining it in `spec/factories/user.rb`

Comment: I tried both options (with factories file, and factories folder), but still doesn't work

Comment: You've likely resolved this by this point, but the issue should be in your config/setup here. I think some of your imports are in the wrong places so it's not able to load the factories correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to upload my project to Heroku, I got this error about Factory:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `factory_bot 'for
>
> ## <Rails :: Application :: Configuration: 0x0000555a7c7f1508>

Apparently I had the line `` `config.factory_bot.definition_file_paths = ['custom / factories']` `` at the end of my module inside of `applications.rb` in config folder.

After removing this line, the "user" problem never reappeared again, and I was able to continue with the test.

Thank you very much to who tried to help me!!

Answer (score 2):

**KeyError:
Factory not registered: "article"**

When I tried checking factories by command `FactoryBot.factories`
resulted me
**<FactoryBot::Registry:0x0000559725ba4a48 @items={}, @name="Factory">**
Which meant factories were not getting registered, due to this custom settings in config

**You can configure by adding the following to config/application.rb or the appropriate environment configuration in config/environments:**

```
config.factory_bot.definition_file_paths = ["custom/factories"]
```

I removed this and it started working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be occurring on the following line

`let(:list) { create(:list, user: user) }`

maybe do `let(:list) { create(:list, user_id: user.id) }` if you are referencing the user from list table using `user_id`

read the error message it's complaining about a `user` key which is `user:`

hope that helps :)

Comment: What rails and ruby versions are you using?

Comment: `Defining 'user' factory in 'spec/factories.rb'`

I think you should define your 'user' factory in it's own file

first, create a directory called `factories` and then inside of there create a file called `users.rb` and move the content from your current `factories.rb` into the `users.rb` factory and delete your `factories.rb`

Comment: If user is an association on the List model, Rails magic should be handling the OP's original assignment syntax correctly. The error is also when it's trying to create the user object, not the list object, so that indicates that there's likely something wrong in their factories/spec configuration. The error is `KeyError: Factory not registered: "user"`, which means that FactoryBot can't find a key called `user` to when attempting to create the `user` test object.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end
```

To

```rb
gem 'factory_bot_rails'
```